# Правильная разметка RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть такой RecyclerView. Нужно, чтобы все элементы нормально помещались (например, дата), а элементы, которые не поместились на экране, можно было посмотреть пролистав влево. Как такое можно реализовать?

Вот разметка item:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/workPeriodLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="5">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/date"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.01dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/user"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/user"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.01dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/explanation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:text="@string/explanation"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.01dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/amount"
        android:textColor="#000" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.01dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_margin="1dp"
        android:background="#e2e2e2" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/order"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Order"
        android:textColor="#000" />


</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0.01dp"
    android:background="#cfcfcf" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Каждый итем отдельно нужно листать влево или весь список вместе?

Comment: Весь список нужно.

Comment: Посмотрите библиотеки из [этого вопроса](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44286207/tablelayout-with-recyclerview)